# WPF Binding ICommand with ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, icommand

ICommand:

```
public class CMDAddEditUser : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public VMAddEditUser ViewModel { get; set;}

    public CMDAddEditUser()
    {
    }

    public CMDAddEditUser(VMAddEditUser vm)
    {
        ViewModel = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }


    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.ViewModel.SimpleMethod();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class VMAddEditUser
{
    private Employee _employee = new Employee();
    private CMDAddEditUser Command { get; set; }

    public VMAddEditUser()
    {
        Command = new CMDAddEditUser(this);
    }

    public string txtFirstName
    {
        get { return _employee.FirstName; }
        set { _employee.FirstName = value; }
    }

    public void SimpleMethod()
    {
        txtFirstName = "abc";
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.AddEditUserView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
        Title="AddEditUserView" Height="392.329" Width="534.143">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-3">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <vm:VMAddEditUser x:Key="abx"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:VMAddEditUser/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding SimpleMethod, Source={StaticResource abx}}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The CMDAddEditUser and VMAddEditUser is in the same project while the xaml is in a different project.

The `.Execute(Object Parameter)` of the ICommand doesn't seem to work. I can't bind the SimpleMethod with the button that I have. When I type the Command Binding in the xaml file, the auto-complete/suggestions only shows  the `txtFirstName` and not the `SimpleMethod`. I can't figure out why the SimpleMethod can't be binded and can't be found. What did I do wrong in this code?

Comment: SimpleMethod is not a command. That's your `Command` property. It should be public, and the binding should be `Command="{Binding Command, ...}"`.

Comment: Your Icommand property is private.  Make it public and bind to that.

Answer (score 0):

First: All properties you want your view to be able to bind to, must be public. Since view binds to property, which is instance of `ICommand` implementation, property must be public, so view can access it. However, your `SimpleMethod()` can be private if you don't wanna expose it to the outside world, that why you have command calling it instead of letting view directly call it.
Second: You set you grids `DataContext` to your 'VMEditUser' class, so in binding there is no need to specify `Source`, `DataContext` is source.